# Cummulative sum with repsect to feature with dtype = interval

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset for which I want to transform to give cummulative percentages. In normal cases, this isn't a hard thing do do, but in this case the cummulation needs to be done on distance bins. So, here is my dataframe:

```
distance_bin  objects in bin  percentage
0   (-0.001, 0.5]         12054       34.24
1      (0.5, 1.0]          6594       18.73
2      (1.0, 1.5]          3547       10.08
3      (1.5, 2.0]          2031        5.77
4      (2.0, 2.5]          1831        5.20
5      (2.5, 3.0]          1654        4.70
6      (3.0, 3.5]          1406        3.99
7      (3.5, 4.0]          1021        2.90
8      (4.0, 4.5]           566        1.61
9      (4.5, 5.0]           515        1.46
10     (5.0, 5.5]           680        1.93
11     (5.5, 6.0]           570        1.62
12     (6.0, 6.5]           324        0.92
13     (6.5, 7.0]           305        0.87
14     (7.0, 7.5]           223        0.63
15     (7.5, 8.0]           257        0.73
16     (8.0, 8.5]           159        0.45
17     (8.5, 9.0]           193        0.55
18     (9.0, 9.5]           179        0.51
19    (9.5, 10.0]           154        0.44
20   (10.0, 10.5]            98        0.28
21   (10.5, 11.0]           132        0.37
22   (11.0, 11.5]           132        0.37
23   (11.5, 12.0]            88        0.25
24   (12.0, 12.5]            65        0.18
25   (12.5, 13.0]            84        0.24
26   (13.0, 13.5]            58        0.16
27   (13.5, 14.0]            80        0.23
28   (14.0, 14.5]            31        0.09
29   (14.5, 15.0]            37        0.11
```

or with the `dtypes` appended:

```
{'distance_bin': {0: Interval(-0.001, 0.5, closed='right'),
  1: Interval(0.5, 1.0, closed='right'),
  2: Interval(1.0, 1.5, closed='right'),
  3: Interval(1.5, 2.0, closed='right'),
  4: Interval(2.0, 2.5, closed='right'),
  5: Interval(2.5, 3.0, closed='right'),
  6: Interval(3.0, 3.5, closed='right'),
  7: Interval(3.5, 4.0, closed='right'),
  8: Interval(4.0, 4.5, closed='right'),
  9: Interval(4.5, 5.0, closed='right'),
  10: Interval(5.0, 5.5, closed='right'),
  11: Interval(5.5, 6.0, closed='right'),
  12: Interval(6.0, 6.5, closed='right'),
  13: Interval(6.5, 7.0, closed='right'),
  14: Interval(7.0, 7.5, closed='right'),
  15: Interval(7.5, 8.0, closed='right'),
  16: Interval(8.0, 8.5, closed='right'),
  17: Interval(8.5, 9.0, closed='right'),
  18: Interval(9.0, 9.5, closed='right'),
  19: Interval(9.5, 10.0, closed='right'),
  20: Interval(10.0, 10.5, closed='right'),
  21: Interval(10.5, 11.0, closed='right'),
  22: Interval(11.0, 11.5, closed='right'),
  23: Interval(11.5, 12.0, closed='right'),
  24: Interval(12.0, 12.5, closed='right'),
  25: Interval(12.5, 13.0, closed='right'),
  26: Interval(13.0, 13.5, closed='right'),
  27: Interval(13.5, 14.0, closed='right'),
  28: Interval(14.0, 14.5, closed='right'),
  29: Interval(14.5, 15.0, closed='right'),
  30: Interval(15.0, 15.5, closed='right'),
  31: Interval(15.5, 16.0, closed='right'),
  32: Interval(16.0, 16.5, closed='right'),
  33: Interval(16.5, 17.0, closed='right'),
  34: Interval(17.0, 17.5, closed='right'),
  35: Interval(17.5, 18.0, closed='right'),
  36: Interval(18.0, 18.5, closed='right'),
  37: Interval(18.5, 19.0, closed='right'),
  38: Interval(19.0, 19.5, closed='right'),
  39: Interval(19.5, 20.0, closed='right'),
  40: Interval(20.0, 20.5, closed='right'),
  42: Interval(21.0, 21.5, closed='right'),
  44: Interval(22.0, 22.5, closed='right'),
  46: Interval(25.0, 25.5, closed='right')},
 'Objects in bin': {0: 12054,
  1: 6594,
  2: 3547,
  3: 2031,
  4: 1831,
  5: 1654,
  6: 1406,
  7: 1021,
  8: 566,
  9: 515,
  10: 680,
  11: 570,
  12: 324,
  13: 305,
  14: 223,
  15: 257,
  16: 159,
  17: 193,
  18: 179,
  19: 154,
  20: 98,
  21: 132,
  22: 132,
  23: 88,
  24: 65,
  25: 84,
  26: 58,
  27: 80,
  28: 31,
  29: 37,
  30: 31,
  31: 22,
  32: 18,
  33: 18,
  34: 5,
  35: 5,
  36: 5,
  37: 4,
  38: 3,
  39: 11,
  40: 4,
  42: 2,
  44: 2,
  46: 3},
 'percentage': {0: 34.24,
  1: 18.73,
  2: 10.08,
  3: 5.77,
  4: 5.2,
  5: 4.7,
  6: 3.99,
  7: 2.9,
  8: 1.61,
  9: 1.46,
  10: 1.93,
  11: 1.62,
  12: 0.92,
  13: 0.87,
  14: 0.63,
  15: 0.73,
  16: 0.45,
  17: 0.55,
  18: 0.51,
  19: 0.44,
  20: 0.28,
  21: 0.37,
  22: 0.37,
  23: 0.25,
  24: 0.18,
  25: 0.24,
  26: 0.16,
  27: 0.23,
  28: 0.09,
  29: 0.11,
  30: 0.09,
  31: 0.06,
  32: 0.05,
  33: 0.05,
  34: 0.01,
  35: 0.01,
  36: 0.01,
  37: 0.01,
  38: 0.01,
  39: 0.03,
  40: 0.01,
  42: 0.01,
  44: 0.01,
  46: 0.01}}
```

where

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 44 entries, 0 to 46
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype            
---  ------        --------------  -----            
 0   distance_bin  44 non-null     interval[float64]
 1   objects in bin  44 non-null     int64            
 2   percentage    44 non-null     float64          
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), interval(1)
memory usage: 1.7 KB
```

If `distance_bin` wasn't of dtype `interval[float64]`, the matter could be resolved with something like:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='distance_bin'))['percentage'].expanding().sum()
```

But this doesn't work.

Any idea on how to solve this? What I basically want is:

```
distance_bin  objects in bin  percentage
0   (-0.001, 0.5]         12054       34.24
1   (-0.001, 1.0]         18648       52.97
2   (-0.001, 1.5]         22195       63.05
3   (-0.001, 2.0]         24226       68.82
4   (-0.001, 2.5]         26057       74.02
....
```

Comment: Your dataframe is not (easily) reproducible. How to recreate interval?

Comment: Also works for me

Comment: You have an `interval` for `distance_bin`?

Comment: @jezrael: Version is '1.2.4'

Comment: How do you load the sample to get the right `dtype`?

Comment: @Corralien: Yes, an interval. Because I needed is for another part of my work.

Comment: @Corralien custom transform to map the string representation to pd.Interval

Comment: @jezrael: It does not "concatenate" the intervals as in the desired output. Does it do it for you?

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes - So does not work means wrong ouput?

Comment: Yes. The output I am looking for is at the end of the question.

Comment: @Corralien: Added the data with dtypes. Reproducible now.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes in fact you want a simple cumsum? check my answer

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes - Thinking about `Intervals`, why are changed in ouput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
right = pd.IntervalIndex(df['distance_bin']).right
df['distance_bin'] = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(list(zip([-0.001]*len(right), right)))
df[['ESL:s in bin', 'percentage']] = df[['ESL:s in bin', 'percentage']].cumsum()
```

```
>>> df
      distance_bin  ESL:s in bin  percentage
0    (-0.001, 0.5]         12054       34.24
1    (-0.001, 1.0]         18648       52.97
2    (-0.001, 1.5]         22195       63.05
3    (-0.001, 2.0]         24226       68.82
4    (-0.001, 2.5]         26057       74.02
5    (-0.001, 3.0]         27711       78.72
6    (-0.001, 3.5]         29117       82.71
7    (-0.001, 4.0]         30138       85.61
8    (-0.001, 4.5]         30704       87.22
9    (-0.001, 5.0]         31219       88.68
10   (-0.001, 5.5]         31899       90.61
11   (-0.001, 6.0]         32469       92.23
12   (-0.001, 6.5]         32793       93.15
13   (-0.001, 7.0]         33098       94.02
14   (-0.001, 7.5]         33321       94.65
15   (-0.001, 8.0]         33578       95.38
16   (-0.001, 8.5]         33737       95.83
17   (-0.001, 9.0]         33930       96.38
18   (-0.001, 9.5]         34109       96.89
19  (-0.001, 10.0]         34263       97.33
20  (-0.001, 10.5]         34361       97.61
21  (-0.001, 11.0]         34493       97.98
22  (-0.001, 11.5]         34625       98.35
23  (-0.001, 12.0]         34713       98.60
24  (-0.001, 12.5]         34778       98.78
25  (-0.001, 13.0]         34862       99.02
26  (-0.001, 13.5]         34920       99.18
27  (-0.001, 14.0]         35000       99.41
28  (-0.001, 14.5]         35031       99.50
29  (-0.001, 15.0]         35068       99.61
30  (-0.001, 15.5]         35099       99.70
31  (-0.001, 16.0]         35121       99.76
32  (-0.001, 16.5]         35139       99.81
33  (-0.001, 17.0]         35157       99.86
34  (-0.001, 17.5]         35162       99.87
35  (-0.001, 18.0]         35167       99.88
36  (-0.001, 18.5]         35172       99.89
37  (-0.001, 19.0]         35176       99.90
38  (-0.001, 19.5]         35179       99.91
39  (-0.001, 20.0]         35190       99.94
40  (-0.001, 20.5]         35194       99.95
42  (-0.001, 21.5]         35196       99.96
44  (-0.001, 22.5]         35198       99.97
46  (-0.001, 25.5]         35201       99.98
```

Comment: C'était un plaisir !

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the bins and use `cumsum` on the wanted column:

```
df[['ESL:s in bin_cumsum', 'percentage_cumsum']] = df.sort_values(by='distance_bin')[['ESL:s in bin', 'percentage']].cumsum()
```

output:

```
    distance_bin  ESL:s in bin  percentage  ESL:s in bin_cumsum  percentage_cumsum
0  (-0.001, 0.5]         12054       34.24                12054              34.24
1     (0.5, 1.0]          6594       18.73                18648              52.97
2     (1.0, 1.5]          3547       10.08                22195              63.05
3     (1.5, 2.0]          2031        5.77                24226              68.82
4     (2.0, 2.5]          1831        5.20                26057              74.02
```

Answer (score 1):

If need manually set `left` parameter for each `Interval` to `-0.001` use:

```
df['distance_bin'] = df['distance_bin'].apply(lambda x: pd.Interval(-0.001, x.right))
cols = ['objects in bin','percentage']
df[cols] = df[cols].cumsum()
print (df.head(10))
    distance_bin  objects in bin  percentage
0  (-0.001, 0.5]           12054       34.24
1  (-0.001, 1.0]           18648       52.97
2  (-0.001, 1.5]           22195       63.05
3  (-0.001, 2.0]           24226       68.82
4  (-0.001, 2.5]           26057       74.02
5  (-0.001, 3.0]           27711       78.72
6  (-0.001, 3.5]           29117       82.71
7  (-0.001, 4.0]           30138       85.61
8  (-0.001, 4.5]           30704       87.22
9  (-0.001, 5.0]           31219       88.68
```

Comment: So, this works very well. In other words, there is no way to, in the final df, make sure to have all intervals starting at ```-0.001```, as in the output I wanted?

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes - Yes, it is possible. Added to answer.